# Indexing latitude and longitude SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, algorithm, google-maps, geolocation

Hi I have database table struture Like following table - ItemLocation

```
ItemId varchar(10)          ItemGeo (geography)
123n13                      POINT (-79.660470500000017 43.5482682)
n4f923                      POINT (-79.7511776 43.6575816)
```

and more rows.......................

And i am using a simple insert to insert the data now, But actually i want to insert the rows by location so that Items which are close will stay together in the database so If a try to insert a new item 'q3eqwe2' which is more close to 123n13 so it will go next to  123n13 and replace n4f923 index and all the bottom rows will move to index + 1. Is this feasible ?

```
ItemId varchar(10)          ItemGeo (geography)
    123n13                      POINT (-79.660470500000017 43.5482682)
    q3eqwe2                     POINT (-79.66039911221 43.5479121)
    n4f923                      POINT (-79.7511776 43.6575816)
```

If it is feasible i dont want to go through all the rows checking ItemGeo column to find the perfect index for new row, so can I add new column which will Index on the basis of the Item location and i can easily find the closest location match to insert? 
Hope it make sense :)

Comment: "Closeness" is a tricky concept, especially if you're trying to keep close points together.  You'll soon find yourself in NP-hard territory.

Comment: so what can be the best to store relatively close items together?

Comment: You can't do that in any meaningful way.

Comment: The order of rows never matters.  You are storing CLR objects anyway.  These are binary blobs.  They are not "at" point -79.1 in any meaningful way.  Spatial indexes create a grid over the whole world, and let you search geography types that way.  Having said that, our tests convinced us to stay with our numeric(18,12) lat long columns, because our numeric index search was just way way faster than spatial indexes.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this? What benefit do you believe it brings that items that are geographically close are stored "close" to each other in the database (whatever that means)? It sounds like you think this will make INSERT operations quicker: it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it does make sense. Effectively with a geography type, you're asking for a two dimensional index mapped onto a globe. If A is close to B, and B is close to C, A could be close to C, or far from C, and then we're into the travelling salesman problem. Where does your index start and end?

You can create a spatial index on your geography type. I think that's the best option.

The root of the question is why do you think you need to?

Comment: hmmm but lets say i already have A and B in the database and i am trying to add C so if distance between A and C is smaller than B and C i want to add the then in sequence like A,C,B

Comment: Then what if D is equidistant from A and B? Where does it go?